# Scan TypeScript Files in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

Sonarproject.properties files has this below information

```
sonar.sources=src
sonar.coverage.exclusions=**/*.test.*
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.test.*
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=./coverage/lcov.info
```

Now when i run the scan, its picking src folder in which it has .js and .ts files. however its only picking .js files

Project type is showing as "Java script", its should show both "javascript and typescript" or only "Typescript"

lines of code is
Null for .ts files
shows up number for .js files

Not sure what need to fixed to read lines of code from src folder for typescript files. [ added pic for reference][SCREEN SHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lSRx.png)

Comment: Not detecting the typescript files, only detecting java script.

Comment: i recommend to rework your question. State first your goal, what do you want to achieve. Then state the process in an well formatted order with information,  `-` are not really good, use an ordered list. always keep in mind, people do miss context and you need to explain it in a good manner. also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask